# Need SQL query to find users with activity in two different periods for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do some analysis on usage of our web based app.
I have a table with the the following columns
    email address
    activity date

I want to create a query that answers this question:
For each day in the past 180 days, how many people who did an activity between 60 and 30 days prior ALSO did an activity between 30 and 0 days prior.

I already have this working as a stored procedure where I literally loop over the past 180 days (using a date table with 1 row per day), but this is kinda slow as I'm doing 180 queries.

I also tried my hand at doing it with one query with the IN clause but it took about 5 minutes to complete (the table only has about 2,000 rows total so I'm guessing it was HIGHLY un-optimized)

How would I do this with one query (or even a stored proc) that's optimized?

Here is the current stored proc (which works but is slow) if it helps:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE mydate DATE;
    DECLARE period1 INT;
    DECLARE period2 INT;
    DECLARE done INT;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT date_value from dim_date  order by date_value DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    SET done = 0;
    OPEN cur;

    REPEAT

    FETCH cur INTO mydate;
    IF NOT done THEN
  REPLACE INTO churn (payment_received,period2,period1,churn_name)

    select
mydate, 
count(distinct(case when (sales.payment_received BETWEEN DATE_SUB(mydate,INTERVAL p2 month) AND DATE_SUB(mydate,INTERVAL p1 month)) then email end)) AS period2,
(
select count(distinct(case when (sales.payment_received BETWEEN DATE_SUB(mydate,INTERVAL p1 month) AND mydate) then email end))
from sales where subscription = 1 AND email in (select email from sales where sales.payment_received BETWEEN DATE_SUB(mydate,INTERVAL p2 month) AND DATE_SUB(mydate,INTERVAL p1 month) ) 
) 
AS period1,
churn_name as cname
from sales 
where subscription = 1;

    END IF;    
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cur;

END;;
```

Thanks!

Comment: why keep activity date?why not no.of times?

Comment: So 30 to 60 days prior to the 180 days? IE for each day in the 180 look at 30-60 and 0-30 with respect to that (180 day) date?

Comment: You should [NOT be using BETWEEN to deal with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (there are some SQL Server-specific issues, but it's the general concept of dealing with the types that's important).  I suspect that your schema is also screwy, given that you have the customer _email_ in your sales table (it should be some sort of unchanging id).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Get users with activity in the last month (DISTINCT cause we don't care how many times in the last month, just weather they were active at all):

```
SELECT DISTINCT email
FROM sales 
WHERE payment_received BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTHS)
```

Step 2) Get users with activity 1-2 months ago:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email
FROM sales 
WHERE payment_received BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTHS) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 MONTHS)
```

Step 3) Join these into one result set

```
SELECT M1.email
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT email
  FROM sales 
  WHERE payment_received BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTHS)
) M1,
(
  SELECT DISTINCT email
  FROM sales 
  WHERE payment_received BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTHS) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 MONTHS)
) M2
WHERE M1.email = M2.email
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that `dim_date` is a calendar table (very handy things)  It might also be nice to know what (if any) indices you may have, but at 2000 rows a decent RDBMS will likely load the entire table into memory *regardless*, so that probably isn't a factor.

Unfortunately, any way you look at it, this type of analysis is going to take time. I'm fairly certain translating this into a completely set-based approach will speed things up, but I don't have an instance to really test against.
I'd start by re-writing the statement like so:

```
SELECT Dim_Date.date_value, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Period_2.email), COUNT(DISTINCT Period_1.email),
       Period_1.churn_name
FROM Dim_Date
JOIN Sales Period_2
  ON Period_2.payment_received >= DATE_SUB(Dim_Date.date_value, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
     AND Period_2.payment_received < DATE_SUB(Dim_Date.date_value, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
     AND Period_2.subscription = 1
LEFT JOIN Sales Period_1
       ON Period_1.payment_received >= DATE_SUB(Dim_Date.date_value, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          AND Period_1.payment_received < Dim_Date.date_value
          AND Period_1.subscription = 1
          AND Period_1.email = Period_2.email
          AND Period_1.churn_name = Period_2.churn_name
WHERE Dim_Date.date_value >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 180 DAY)
      AND Dim_Date.date_value < CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY Dim_Date.date_value, Period_1.churn_name
```

This statement should run, but is otherwise untested.
(...I'm not sure what I was thinking here originally, I wasn't correlating the two sets *per-user*...)

One thing - you don't seem to have `subscription = 1` as a condition on the inner-most subquery; I didn't know if that was deliberate, or an oversight.  I've also assumed that `churn_name` should be correlated, whatever that is.